# vLAN conflict with multi site to site vpn

Tags: openvpn, vlan, ipsec

I have a multiple location and decided to have the same vlans on each location for each port group
I have vlan10 as management vlan20 guest .... vlan100 as WIFI the IP address for example vlan10 site 1 will be something like this 10.11.0.0/16 2nd octet will sum vlan+location
I am going to connect each site with site to site VPN IPSEC or OPENVPN I haven't decided yet I can accept any suggestion for that also 
My question is am I going have any conflict if I use the same VLAN # when I connect the sites with site to site vpn

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

VLANs are layer-2 constructs, and are bounded by a layer-3 device. You can even use the same VLAN numbers on different router interfaces on the same router.

What you cannot do is connect using the same layer-3 addressing, unless you use a NAT between the sites.

Comment: What is your recommendation about using IPSEC and OPENVPN witch one is better and most secure